# Incosistent QLabels with QPixmaps resizing behavior inside horizontal layout while keeping aspect ratio of images

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qpixmap

I am trying to create an image editor using PyQt5.

I sub-classed `QLabel` to create a label which displays an image through `setPixmap`. The class ensures that, whenever the label is resized, the image maintains aspect ratio.

I put 2 of those labels inside a horizontal layout and set their pixmaps to 2 images.

All works great, except when the window is resized in certain ways.

When I start increasing width of the window, everything works great. But when I start shrinking it, the first label start shrinking, while *the second one stays the same*. The first label keeps shrinking until it can't decrease in size anymore, forcing the second one to shrink.

This is not what I want. I want *both labels to stay the same size* while window gets resized. How can I accomplish that?

Here is minimal part of my code to reproduce my problem:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class ImageLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMinimumSize(1,1)
        self.setScaledContents(False)

        self.pixmap = QPixmap(1, 1)

    def set_image(self, image_path):
        pixmap = QPixmap(image_path)
        self.set_pixmap(pixmap)

    def set_pixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.setPixmap(self.scaled_pixmap())

    def scaled_pixmap(self):
        return self.pixmap.scaled(
            self.size(),
            Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
            Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()
        self.start()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Image Editor')

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.image_1 = ImageLabel()
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.image_1)

        self.image_2 = ImageLabel()
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.image_2)

        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.hlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.resize(800, 600)

    def start(self):
        self.image_1.set_image(
            r"orig.jpg"
        )

        self.image_2.set_image(
            r"edit.jpg"
        )

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MainWindow()

mainWindow.show()
exitCode = app.exec_()

sys.exit(exitCode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using QLabel, the simplest is to use a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsPixmapItem:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ImageLabel(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene())
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff) 
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def setImage(self, filename):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(filename))

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        item.setTransformationMode(QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.scene().addItem(item)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        r = self.scene().itemsBoundingRect()
        self.fitInView(r, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        super(ImageLabel, self).resizeEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()
        self.start()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Image Editor')

        self.image_1 = ImageLabel()
        self.image_2 = ImageLabel()

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.image_1)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.image_2)

        self.resize(800, 600)

    def start(self):
        self.image_1.setImage(
            r"orig.jpg"
        )

        self.image_2.setImage(
            r"edit.jpg"
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    mainWindow.show()
    exitCode = app.exec_()

    sys.exit(exitCode)
```